# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion

Tags: asp.net

I am building webform  using `vs2012 Express`. I am using the `ASP.NET Membership provider`.
In configuring the `sqlmembershipprovider`, I ran the following sql batch on my db.

```
\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.030319\InstallCommon.sql
\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.030319\InstallMembership.sql
```

to install the Membership.When i tried to Register new  user on my application I received the following Error Message:

Exception Details:
 `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'`.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1769462
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5318578
.......
```

Going through the trace and Answers on similar question posted on stack overflow, I notice that I run the two `sqlbatches` on a wrong `db:A`. I created similar table on db:A and change the connection string in the web congfig. it works.But the `db:B` am working on is where I want install the membership, when I ran the same `sqlbatches` on this `db:B` the necessary objects are not installed.Both databases are on the same server.
Did any know why and what should i do next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct method of setting up the membership provider database is to run the asp.net reg tool. It can be found in the location below:

`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<FrameworkVersion>\aspnet_regsql.exe"`

More information
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Spike.This is very fast and easy.My Registration works now

Comment: Note: this also works for LocalDb - just enter "(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB" and select windows authentication.